# Как показать код в определенное время года на php?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как показать код (картинку в углу сайта) в определенное время года на php. Например с 15 декабря по 15 января (каждого года).

Comment: А вы сами пробовали что-то?

Comment: Вы пытались как-то решить эту задачу собственными силами? Приведите пример своего решения, и мы подскажем, в чем ваша ошибка и как ее устранить. 

Вам следует прочесть следующие разделы справки: 
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
[Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
После этого отредактируйте вопрос и приведите его к рекомендуемому виду.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой рабочий вариант (помогли с другого форума)

```
<?php
$time_now = time(); // время сейчас в секундах
$date_start = date( '15.12.Y' ); // 15.01.2020
$date_end  = date( '15.01.' ) . ( (int)date('Y') + 1 ); // 15.01.2021
$time_start = strtotime($date_start); // переводим в секунды
$time_end  = strtotime($date_end ); // переводим в секунды
if( $time_now >= $time_start && $time_now <= $time_end  ) { // сравниваем в секундах
    echo 'something'; // выводим что-то
}
echo date( 'd.m.Y H:i:s', $time_now );  // дата сейчас
```

Comment: Оставьте ссылку на источник